# How to read the Modulo operator in a formula

Tags: mathematics, programming

Because I am a programmer, I have been reading tutorials and manuals about programming in Japanese.

For the most part I am ok with all of the terminology, both from the computing side and maths side.

However I have just been reading about the Modulo Operator `(剰余演算子)` and have no idea how to read in in a formula.

For example `加算` means `Addition`, but you would read the `加算演算子` as `足す` in a formula like `1 + 2 = 3`.

I know that 剰余 means Remainder (or modulus), but I doubt you would say that when reaidng a formula.
All I can think of for example is:

```
4 % 2 = 0
よん　モジュロ　に　は　れい/ゼロ
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind splitting your questions into two separate questions? It makes them easier to find if someone is searching for the answers later, since searches are heavily affected by titles. (as a bonus, more rep!)

Comment: Of course, I'll move the Negation related part into another question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1122105076

> mod は、modulo(モジュロ) の省略で、モッドと読みます。

Someone deleted his answer but he was also right in a way.

`a % b` is also read `a を b で割った余り`.

Answer (score 4):

The word `modulo` is read `モジュロ`, while the abbreviation `mod` is read `モッド`.  In many programming languages, the modulo operator is written with a symbol such as `%`, but it still *represents* either `modulo` or `mod`, so you could read the symbol either way.

```
Written form        Reading
-----------------   --------------------
x modulo y          x モジュロ y
x mod y             x モッド y
x % y               x モジュロ y     OR     x モッド y
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, like I said on Ryo's answer I wish I could accept all of these, but I'll go with oldergod's answer simply because they also provided another way to read the formula which I am seeing a lot now that I know what I am looking for.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I think I learnt in elementary math that

```
22 % 3 = 1
```

would be read as

```
22を3で割るところの余りは1
```

Hence, I would read the example in the original question as

```
4を2で割るところの余りは0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wish I could accept all of these answers but I am going with oldergod's answer because now that I know what I am looking for I'm seeing aをbで割った余り more than aをbで割るところの余り.